# @Valid Bean validation not working in jersey

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

In my pom.xml file i have these fallowing dependencies added

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
     <version>2.25.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

and in my CustomApplication class which extends `ResourceConfig` i have registered these 2 fallowing properties

```
property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true); 
property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
```

I have a DTO (POJO) like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

public class PlotDTO {

private String guid;
@NotNull
private String plot_name;
@NotNull
private String farmer_id;
@NotNull
private float distance_from_warehouse;
@NotNull
private int area;
@NotNull
private float sand;
.............
.............
}
```

And in my resource class i am trying to validate this  usingg `@Valid`

```
@Path("addplot")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addPlot(@Valid PlotDTO plot) 
{
 ..............
 ..............
}
```

when i send an request none of these @NotNull validations are working

can some one help me with this

Comment: Is it for all of them or just the primitives?

Comment: Some of them are required fields . It not matter of primitives

Comment: My point is that primitives can't be null.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me . yeah i don't want negative or zero values in int, and float , do you have any suggestion .Should i write logic for that in action layer

Comment: What about [`@Min(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html)?

Comment: What about float values. i need them greater than zero but not zero something like 0.48 is valid

Comment: I am not completely sure. Google around. If you can't find something that works for you, it is not too difficult to [write your own validator](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13779).

Comment: That is why I asked the question in my first comment.

Comment: @peeskillet yes you are right "@NotNull" is effective only on Strings and Wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@NotNull
```

annotation is effective only on Strings and Wrappers . it will not work on primitives like int , float, and boolean , etc because they already have default values .

Answer (score -3):

Please do the following to get validation. It works for me.

1. Class implementing  `Validator`, `InitializingBean` for Spring
2. Class implementing `ContextResolver<ValidationConfig>` for Jersey configuration.
3. Class implementing `ExceptionMaper<ConstraintViolationException>`

   ```
   @Component
   public class BeanValidator implements Validator,InitializingBean {
       private Validator validator;

       public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
           ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
           validator = validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
       }

       public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
           return true;
       }

       public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
           Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(target);
           for (ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
               String propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
               String message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
               errors.rejectValue(propertyPath, "", message);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public ExecutableValidator forExecutables() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public BeanDescriptor getConstraintsForClass(Class<?> arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(T arg0, Class<?>... arg1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateProperty(T arg0, String arg1, Class<?>... arg2) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateValue(Class<T> arg0, String arg1, Object arg2, Class<?>... arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }
   }

   2. Jersey configuration Classes.
   @Provider
   public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {
       @Context
       private ResourceContext resourceContext;    

       /**Get a context*/
       @Override
       public ValidationConfig getContext(Class<?> type) {
           final ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
           config.constraintValidatorFactory(resourceContext.getResource(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.class));
           config.parameterNameProvider(new CustomParameterNameProvider());
           return config;
       }

       private class CustomParameterNameProvider implements ParameterNameProvider {
           private final ParameterNameProvider nameProvider;
           public CustomParameterNameProvider() {
               nameProvider = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().getDefaultParameterNameProvider();
           }

           @Override
           public List<String> getParameterNames(final Constructor<?> constructor) {
               return nameProvider.getParameterNames(constructor);
           }

           @Override
           public List<String> getParameterNames(final Method method) {
               return nameProvider.getParameterNames(method);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   If your using maven you can achieve internalization and localisation by using ValidationMessages.properties putting in resource path. Please refer below link [Github- bean-validation-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp)

Comment: _"Basically Jersey aren't able to understand @Valid annotations directly."_ == False.

Comment: Hi @peeskillet, above solution works for me. Without using the above classes, jersey can't able to validate with 'javax.validation' annotation.  You can refer above github project for further clarification.

Comment: Please try this solution [CustomApplication](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/beanvalidation/webapp/MyApplication.java). This configuration based on java and jersey alone.